# Google Sheets: FILTER but keep all columns together on FILTER'ed list

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have two sheets (1: Roster, and 2: Training).  I want the NAME listed on tab:Roster to display on tab:Training.  I have that working just fine, but the issue is when the list on Roster is modified (order is changed) the rest of the columns on tab:Training stay put.  I'd like ALL the columns on tab:Training to "follow" any movement by the FILTER list.

**IMAGES**:
tab:Roster list
[![This is tab:Roster][1]][1]


Here is tab:Training where the names are listed.  Except when the list I created using FILTER on tab:Roster is sorted, the rest of the columns on tab:Training remain where they are and don't sort along with the list of names.
[![tab:Training][2]][2]


Here is the "aftermath" of sorting tab:Roster
[![tab:Training][3]][3]

OR - Better yet, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm wanting to accomplish?  The end goal is to have one list be maintained (tab:Roster) and the rest of the tabs will update accordingly.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCii0.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxStd.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEGcy.jpg

Comment: See [Should I use tags in titles?](/help/tagging)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output